# Creating a script to find a cateID through multiple tables in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, loops

I have 3 tables. I am trying to find out the `category ID` for a product so where it sits onto our website. There are 2 levels of categories.

First table is `products` and it has the `ID` associated with the product.

1st table: `Product`

```
Product     PrimaryCateID
Tennis Ball         6
```

2nd table: `Group`

```
GroupID     Group       CateID      
1       Football        8   
2           Basketball      9   
3       Snooker         10
4       Tennis          11
```

3rd table: `SubGroup`

```
GroupID     Subgroup        CateID
4       Equipment       6
4       Area            7
```

I am trying to create a script to find the `Category` that the tennis ball will appear on the website.

So looking at the tables the tennis ball has a `PrimaryCateID` of 6 which should appear on the site under the `Equipment` group level.

How do I create the script to loop through all the tables (the 2 group tables) to find the `primaryCateID` the product is assigned to?

Comment: You need to gain some basic SQL knowledge - start with reading about "joining tables" - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191472(v=sql.105).aspx and "user defined functions" - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    [Group].[GroupID],
    [Group].[Group]
FROM
    Product
    INNER JOIN SubGroup ON Product.PrimaryCateID = SubGroup.CateID
    INNER JOIN [Group] ON SubGroup.GroupID = [Group].GroupID
WHERE
    Product.Product = 'Tennis Ball'
```